# I cant access to my design form with the error "Values cannot be null. (Parameter 'baseName')"

Tags: vb.net

When I tried to open my design form, an error shows up and says `Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'baseName')`  Then I cant access to my design form.

I've tried to restart my Visual Studio, but it still wont work.

The instance for this error are

`` at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.d__143`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Host.ServerHost.d__15.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task  task) at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.d__28.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.d__28.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task  task) at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.<>c__DisplayClass24_1.<<- ctor>b__1>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task  task) at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.d__26.MoveNext() ``